# Whenever I do a reloadAtIndexpath in a tableview, the particular tableview cell appears to move upwards - Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, reload

The issue occurs while scrolling down the tableview and then updating the particular cell index.

Tried  .fade and .none animations while reloading at index.  Also tried tableView.beginUpdates() and endupdates(). But none of the them worked out.

Comment: Please include code sample which you have tried. This helps others to replicate the issue and suggest.